# Rearranging an array with key value

Tags: php, arrays, d3.js, multidimensional-array

Suppose,
I have an array

```
$my_array = array(
    array(
        array('cnt' => 1, 'date' => '2016-06-18', 'name' => 'Phone Calls'),
        array('cnt' => 1,'date' => '2016-06-18','name' => 'Others Works')
    ),
    array(
        array('cnt' => 2 , 'date' => '2016-06-17', 'name' => 'Phone Calls'),
        array('cnt' => 1, 'date' => '2016-06-17', 'name' => 'Others Works'),
        array('cnt' => 1, 'date' => '2016-06-17', 'name' => 'Deal with Customer')
    ),
     array(
        array('cnt' => 4 , 'date' => '2016-06-15', 'name' => 'Phone Calls'),
        array('cnt' => 5, 'date' => '2016-06-15', 'name' => 'Others Works'),
        array('cnt' => 6, 'date' => '2016-06-15', 'name' => 'Deal with Customer')
    )
   .....
);
```

which I need to convert into

```
$desired_result = array(
    array('date' => '2016-06-18', 
         'Phone Calls' => 1,//value is cnt of my_array
         'Others Works' => 1,//value is cnt of my_array
    ),
    array('date' => '2016-06-17', 
        'Phone Calls' => 2,//value is cnt of my_array
        'Others Works' => 1,//value is cnt of my_array
        'Deal with Customer' => 1,   
    ),
    array('date' => '2016-06-15', 
        'Phone Calls' => 4,//value is cnt of my_array
        'Others Works' => 5,//value is cnt of my_array
        'Deal with Customer' => 6,   
    )
    .......
);
```

which I need to group by array with date with same array name as key and cnt as value.Can anyone suggest me how can I format this array.

I want to try http://bl.ocks.org/katirg/5f168b5c884b1f9c36a5.

I am new to d3js, so I think better I will format my array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to loop the outer array and then each of those arrays. Take the index name and create an index in a new array that has a value of that arrays cnt.

```
$my_array = array(
    array(
        array('cnt' => 1, 'date' => '2016-06-18', 'name' => 'Phone Calls'),
        array('cnt' => 1,'date' => '2016-06-18','name' => 'Others Works')
    ),
    array(
        array('cnt' => 2 , 'date' => '2016-06-17', 'name' => 'Phone Calls'),
        array('cnt' => 1, 'date' => '2016-06-17', 'name' => 'Others Works'),
        array('cnt' => 1, 'date' => '2016-06-17', 'name' => 'Deal with Customer')
    ),
    array(
        array('cnt' => 4 , 'date' => '2016-06-15', 'name' => 'Phone Calls'),
        array('cnt' => 5, 'date' => '2016-06-15', 'name' => 'Others Works'),
        array('cnt' => 6, 'date' => '2016-06-15', 'name' => 'Deal with Customer')
    )
);

$betterFormat = array();
foreach($my_array as $arrays){
    $newArray = array();

    //Assume the date is the same in both arrays
    $newArray['date'] = $arrays[0]['date'];

    foreach($arrays as $arr){
      $newArray[$arr['name']] = $arr['cnt'];
    }

    $betterFormat[] = $newArray;
}
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($betterFormat);
```

The output is

```
array(3) {
    [0]=> array(3) {
        ["date"]=> string(10) "2016-06-18"
        ["Phone Calls"]=> int(1)
        ["Others Works"]=> int(1)
    }
    [1]=> array(4) {
        ["date"]=> string(10) "2016-06-17"
        ["Phone Calls"]=> int(2)
        ["Others Works"]=>int(1)
        ["Deal with Customer"]=> int(1)
    }
    [2]=> array(4) {
        ["date"]=> string(10) "2016-06-15"
        ["Phone Calls"]=> int(4)
        ["Others Works"]=> int(5)
        ["Deal with Customer"]=> int(6)
    }
}
```

Comment: But $my_array can be with any depth.